# Swift Alamofire post "Extra argument in call"

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to post some xml to an url. This is my code:

```
func post(){
    var data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Devices><Device><ID>EZR0114AF</ID><HEATAREA nr=\"4\"><T_TARGET>17.0</T_TARGET></HEATAREA></Device></Devices>"

    Alamofire.request(urlPost, .post, parameters: data, encoding: .utf8, headers: nil).response { (response) in
        print(response.data)
        print(response.error)
        print(response.response)
    }
}
```

But I get a Syntax error: `Extra argument in call`. I have no idea what is missing, I tried a lot but nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the syntax to

```
 let urlString = "XXXXXXXXX"

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["id": "1,2,3,4"] ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseString {

            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let responseString1):
                print("the response is: \(responseString1)")

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print("The error is: \(error)")
            }
        }
```